# Zend Framework: Fill form with data from mapper

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, datamapper

There is an example of getting data **from form** using mapper in official [quickstart](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.create-form.html). But there is no example in the whole Internet of **populating form** with data **from mapper** (for usual edit action, for example).

I usually do something like this (without using mapper and dbTable):

```
class News_Model_Form_News extends Zend_Form {

private $id = 0;

public function getId(){
    return $this->id;
}

public function setId($id){
    $this->id = $id;
}

public function init() {

    $model = new News_Model_Backend();

    //if form is needed for adding action
    if (!$this->id) {
        //form code
    } else {
    //if form is needed for edit action (fill with values)
        //form code with values
    }
}}
```

But with mapper pattern this stuff should became more elegent and cool, but I don't know how to do this.

So the question is how to populate form with values using mapper pattern (for edit guestbook entry from quickstart, for example)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public function init() {

    $model = new News_Model_Backend();
    $this->populate($model->toArray());
...
```

Comment: To expand: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.forms.html#zend.form.forms.elements.values

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
$form->populate($model->find($id)->current()->toArray());
```